# UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x97' in position 206: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python

Windows 7
Version Python36-32
Code purpose: parsing of web-site

Could you advice please what is the possible reason for error?
I have included coding utf-8 in the beginning and (encoding = 'windows_1252', errors = 'replace') in function "open"
It helped me in other similar parser of other web-site, but for this one does not work

**Piece of code:

```
# cycle through pages
     for i in range (count):
         s = str (i + 1)
         print (s, end = '')
         # make url
         url = url1 + s + url2 + str (status) + url3
         # get html file from server by url
         r = requests.get (url)
         # open file to save with full path to file name
         name = path + 'upload' + s + '.html'
         f = open (name, 'w', encoding = 'windows_1252', errors = 'replace')
         # save url data to file
         f.write (r.text)
         # close file
         f.close ()
         # download files through the list
         parseList (name, s + '.html')

     print ()
     return
```

Error text:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\u6030283\Desktop\FINAM\finam_parser_new.py", line 478, in <module>
    parse('list', 'html', 'XS1272198265')
  File "C:\Users\u6030283\Desktop\FINAM\finam_parser_new.py", line 262, in parse
    f.write(r.text)
  File "C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x97' in position 206: character maps to <undefined>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

The problem is not from the code above (writing file) but in `parse()` nor `parseList()` methods or from reading file.

replace the following

```
# in parseList(...)
text = open(url, 'r')

# and in parse(..)
text = open(path + file, 'r')
```

with

```
# in parseList(...)
text = open(url, 'r', encoding='windows_1252')

# and in parse(..)
text = open(path + file, 'r', encoding='windows_1252')
```

And don't forget to restore your code in your question above to original state.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\u6030283\Desktop\FINAM\finam_parser_new.py", line 475, in <module>
    upload(5,'upload', 4)
  File "C:\Users\u6030283\Desktop\FINAM\finam_parser_new.py", line 163, in upload
    f.write(r.text.encode('utf-8'))
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: Other mistake appeared

Comment: try removing `encoding = 'windows_1252', errors = 'replace'`

Comment: Same mistake :(

Comment: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x97' in position 206: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: may I know URL you're trying to save

Comment: Can I send you whole py folder? You will save it on desktop and just click launch

Comment: if it not private things you can upload zipped file to file hosting

Comment: Folder FINAM should be saved on desktop, and then file "finam_parser_old.py" should be launched (I am using IDLE) 
  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v3wvn3s9uoevwi5/AAAp8Eo9UgfRUMhVbXhBwRHha?dl=0

Comment: Results of parsing are saved in file "result.xlsx"

Comment: I changed according to your advice but (file updated on the link in dropbox).. File "C:\Users\u6030283\Desktop\FINAM\finam_parser_old.py", line 287, in <module>
    parse('list', 'html')
  File "C:\Users\u6030283\Desktop\FINAM\finam_parser_old.py", line 179, in parse
    f.write(r.text)
  File "C:\Users\u6030283\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\x97' in position 206: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: `line 175` has no `, encoding='windows_1252'`

Comment: It works! But only after I added "errors = 'replace' " to each encoding='windows_1252'

Comment: so final part should be "encoding='windows_1252',errors = 'replace'"

Comment: I am new user here, will search now how I can rate your response

Comment: great, there is check mark and upvote icon beside the answer.